# How to Combine two dictionaries in an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary with suppose 10 set of dictionaries in it. In this each of the two dictionaries are couple i.e. they have a specific key whose values are same.

Now, I need to combine these two dictionaries based upon this specific key/id. So in my final output i will get an array of dictionary with 5 set of dictionaries(combining 2 each)

In the below set of example you can see that the pair of dictionaries whose age is same I am trying to combine them into one.

```
[ 
 {
   name : John
   age : 26
   eyes : blue
 },
 {
   name : Becky
   age : 26
   eyes : black
 },
 {
   name : Ron
   age : 30
   eyes : brown
 },
 {
   name : Rose
   age : 30
   eyes : yellow
 }
]
```

and

```
[ 
 {
   name1 : John
   name2 : Becky
   age : 26
   eyes1 : blue
   eyes2 : black

 },

 {
   name1 : Ron
   name2 : Rose
   age : 30
   eyes1 : brown
   eyes2 : yellow
 }
]
```

Comment: can you show exactly what the input and the expected result is?

Answer (score 0):

What you want essentially is to *group* your dictionaries by some key (`age` in this example).

Something like this would do the job

```
let persons: [[String: Any]] = [ 
 [
    "name" : "John",
    "age" : 26,
    "eyes" : "blue"
 ],
 [
    "name" : "Becky",
    "age" : 26,
    "eyes" : "black"
 ],
 [
    "name" : "Ron",
    "age" : 30,
    "eyes" : "brown"
 ],
 [
    "name" : "Rose",
    "age" : 30,
    "eyes" : "yellow"
 ]
]

let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: persons, by: { $0["age"] as? Int })

print(grouped)
```

which gives you

```
[Optional(30): [["age": 30, "eyes": "brown", "name": "Ron"], ["age": 30, "eyes": "yellow", "name": "Rose"]], Optional(26): [["eyes": "blue", "age": 26, "name": "John"], ["eyes": "black", "name": "Becky", "age": 26]]]
```

Note that you could force unwrap (`$0["age"] as! Int`) if you can guarantee that all of your objects would always have an `Int` value, in order to avoid groupings of optional ints.

I hope that this makes sense

Comment: That's not what the questioner asked for, but it gets you half way there.

Comment: @DanielT. OP's suggested solution (dictionary merging) to a grouping problem was deliberately omitted in my answer; I still consider it wrong and thus proposed an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have a crazy construct that you have to transform to. It doesn't seem very useful but if you really need the data in that format, here's what will do it:

```
func example(objects: [AnyObject]) -> [[String: Any]] {
    let input = objects as! [[String: Any]]
    return Dictionary.init(grouping: input, by: { $0["age"] as! Int })
        .mapValues {
            $0.map { (obj) -> [String: Any] in
                var out = obj
                out.removeValue(forKey: "age")
                return out
            }
        }
        .map { (each) -> [String: Any] in
            var dict: [String: Any] = ["age": each.key]
            for obj in each.value.enumerated() {
                for c in obj.element {
                    let key = "\(c.key)\(obj.offset + 1)"
                    dict[key] = c.value
                }
            }
            return dict
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Daniel thanks for the assistance, I tried your provided snippet arranging according to my requirement so I am basically using my input content as [(AnyObject)] format and you are applying [[String : Any]] merging up all the set of dictionaries at first itself. So at the end it is only processing last two element of the array of dictionaries. I believe you can assist me with this too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you go, now the input is `[AnyObject]`

Answer (score 0):

You can run a for loop on the dictionary you want to input, one or the other don't think it would matter in this case

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func append(_ other:Dictionary) {
        // you can do a check here; write a guard checking if the one you're trying to add should be added
        for (key,value) in other {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey:key)
        }
    }

}
```

use that to apppend to the dictionary you want to add to